# How to enable cross origin isolation? (the specifics)

Tags: browser, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I am hosting a website using 1and1 (ionos), and it is serving a HTML page with imported CSS and JS. I am trying to figure out how to enable cross origin isolation, but all I can find is that we need to enable certain response headers: https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/.

Specifically in these instructions:

[image]

What does it mean to set a header on a top-level document? How does one accomplish this? I have done plenty of searching but have not found details on how to create/enable these response headers.

I need to do this in order to use SharedArrayBuffer in Firefox.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the article you linked to. This question sounds like more of a question how to use IONOS than what is cross-origin isolation. I think the best thing you can do now is to ask IONOS how to configure a custom HTTP response header.

Comment: Yeah I was able to work it out with them, thanks! It seems like I was using the wrong service from them, I'm switching to Firebase anyways so I'll be able to handle this much more easily with Firebase.

Comment: Might be useful: You can launch Chrome with a command line flag --enable-features=SharedArrayBuffer to enable SharedArrayBuffer without enabling cross-origin isolation. Source: https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/